# Running Gojs-Angular in debug mode

Tags: angularjs, typescript, webpack, gojs

Can anyone please explain the steps to run Gojs-angular in debug mode. The Gojs documentation explains to use the raw gojs debug file. But if the project is in Gojs-angular Typescript. How can we load the debug module?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest temporarily renaming the node_modules/gojs/release/go.js file and then renaming the go-debug.js file as go.js.  (Or do the same with the *module.js files, if you are using ES modules.)  Then rebuild your project.